# how to add hour onto time script in linux

Tags: linux, date, time, stamp

I have a webcam that uploads a pic to a webpage every 5 minutes and beneath it is some code to upload a timestamp. Recently I have noticed the timestamp is an hour out and Ive checked the linux server, webcam taking images and they have the correct time so not sure what has happened. I suspect its some daylight saving issue but I cant find it so just want to do a temp fix for now.

Heres the code I use to timestamp the image, how can I add an hour onto this? Everything I have tried just results in it not showing the timestamp at all?

```
echo "- Image Uploaded: " . date ("F d Y H:i:s", filemtime($filename));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is `php`, you can set a timezone in your script
with eg

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');
```

See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) for the list of timezones.